# $n$th prime & prime number theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime. If $\pi(n)\sim \dfrac{n}{\log (n)}$ then $p_n\sim n\log n$ (Hardy 1938). A closer approximation is $\pi(n)\sim\text{Li}(n)$. Is there a similarly improved definition for $p_n$?

NB - I felt this was intrinsically a different question to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803935/how-do-we-prove-p-n-sim-n-logn-logn-from-the-prime-number-theorem), and possibly an extension of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331271/the-prime-number-theorem-and-the-nth-prime).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, see e.g. P. Dusart: [The kth prime is greater than k(log k + log log k - 1) for k>=2](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-01037-6/), Math. Comp. **68**, p 411, 1999, or online at 
http://functions.wolfram.com/13.03.06.0004.01:

$$p_n \approx n \left(\log(n) + \log(\log(n)) - 1 + \frac{\log(\log(n)) - 2}{\log(n)}\\
- \frac{\log(\log(n))^2 - 6 \log(\log(n)) + 11}{2 \log(n)^2} \;+ \dots\right),\quad n>2
$$

Comment: Great reference - thanks!

Comment: Do you know if there is an English translation of Cipolla's 1902 proof of this expansion?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know of such a translation.

Comment: Many thanks anyway :)

Comment: There is an other work from Dusart (Sharper bounds for $\psi, \theta, \pi, p_k$: http://www.unilim.fr/laco/rapports/1998/R1998_06.pdf or 
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.165.6978&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Small note - this expansion is very similar to $n\log(n\log(n))$ for small $n$.

Answer (score 4):

See also [The n-th prime asymptotically](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5413) by Juan Arias de Reyna and Toulisse Jeremy.