# Prime number theorem $n^{\rm th}$ prime bounds

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

In [this Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875520/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-this-subset-of-the-primes-converge) post, the accepted answer begins with:

"*Because of the Prime Number Theorem, ultimately we have:*
$$.9\,n\,\log n \leq p_n \leq 1.1 \,n\,\log n.$$
*where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime*".

Where do the bounds of $.9$ and $1.1$ come from? Wikipedia states that:

$$
0.921<\frac{\pi(n)}{n\log(n)}<1.018,
$$

for $10<n<10^{25}$, but other than experimental evidence, how can one be sure that these are really the correct bounds?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for the link. However, my question refers to the explicit bounds of $.9$ and $1.1$, those are not discussed in that other post.

Comment: These are arbitrary choices. From the prime number theorem, it follows that $p_n \sim n\log n$, so for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $N(\varepsilon)$ such that $(1-\varepsilon)n\log n < p_n < (1+\varepsilon) n\log n$ for all $n \geqslant N(\varepsilon)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prime number theorem gives that $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$, in the sense that
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \pi(x) / \frac{x}{\log x} = 1.$$
[This is equivalent to the fact that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803935/how-do-we-prove-p-n-sim-n-logn-logn-from-the-prime-number-theorem/803986#803986) $p_n \sim n \log n$, also in the sense that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{p_n}{n \log n} = 1.$$
In particular, this means that there exists some $N$ such that for all $n > N$, we have
$$ 0.9 < \frac{p_n}{n \log n} < 1.1.$$
There is nothing special about $0.9$ and $1.1$ in this, except that $0.9 < 1$ and $1 < 1.1$. We could replace those two numbers with any other such numbers. We should note that it is (currently) unclear how large $N$ should actually be, and efforts to understand the explicit rate of convergence are wide and varied within the literature (and a speciality of people like Dusart).

Answer (score 1):

Those coefficients have nothing special.

We know that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_n}{n\log n}=1$$

That is, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that if $n\ge N$ we have
$$1-\epsilon<\frac{p_n}{n\log n}<1+\epsilon$$
Now take $\epsilon=0.1$.